# Ejecutar funcion de angular dentro de jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular6

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en angular, quiero hacer que al momento de que el scroll del usuario esté hasta abajo automáticamente le carguen más publicaciones (eso ya lo hace apretando un botón, pero no en automático cuando su scroll está hasta abajo). Con jquery hago que ejecute algo cuando el scroll está hasta abajo, pero no logro hacer que ejecute mi función del componente de angular, aquí mi codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nótese que cuando llamo a la función/metodo desde fuera de angular si la reconoce, pero desde dentro no, lo reconoce como tipo any y al ejecutar en el navegador en el compilador de angular me dice que no existe la función cargarMas()
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se debe porque el `this` dentro de la función apunta al objeto de jQuery, debido que usas

`.. function() { ... }`

```js
const BOTON = $('button');

BOTON.click( function(e) {

  console.log( this === window ); // false
  console.log( this === e.currentTarget ); // true
  console.log( this === BOTON.get(0) ); // true
   
});

BOTON.click( e => {

  console.log( this === window ); // true
  console.log( this === e.currentTarget ); // false
  console.log( this === BOTON.get(0) ); // false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Ver donde apuntan los this</button>
```

Más info sobre [Funciones Flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Soluciones simples:

1. Usa `()=>` (Funciones Flecha)
2. Asignar una variable fuera del la función de jQuery:

`let _this = this;`

y usarlo dentro de la función de jQuery:

`_this.cargarMas();`